# I want to bring a .ascx file into VS2012 and view it

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, .net-4.0, .net-4.5

I have an ascx file that I want to view as the end user will see it.  While it was written in notepad, I have VS 2012 and figure I could view it there or launch it to a browser from there.

How would I do this?

Comment: ascx is a user control - it has to be a part of ASPX page if you want to see it how end user does

Answer (score 0):

An *'.ascx'* file is a User Control, as a *'.aspx'* us a Page. If you are interested in seeing what is on the page, you could save it as .html instead and then start removing any server side references on the file, such as the following tags:

```
<asp:Literal .. />
<% ... %>
<%@ Control Language="C#" ... %>
```

It will probably leave you with a shell of what it was, but enough to perhaps deduct what it was for, unless of course you need the functionality, at which point I would say do you have the DLL's? Or even the web folder, and the associated code behind file, for example:

```
test.ascx.cs
test.ascx.designer.cs
```

Comment: Darn.  99% of the file is controls.  When presented, it is a survey the users can respond to and someone can extract those responses.

Comment: If you don't mind me asking - what is the purpose of the ascx? Are you looking to get it working?

Answer (score 0):

creating the .aspx file to hold the control in VS 2012 is pretty easy, create a basic web form template and in the top add (if your control was named text.ascx for example):

```
<%@ Register TagPrefix="My" TagName="Test" Src="~/test.ascx" %>
```

then somewhere in in your form tags put:

```
<My:Test runat="server" ID="test1" />
```

Hope this helps.